# Margins that don't respond

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a "Read more" button on Section-e that acts weird: the margins are not responding except for left one.

GitHub Repo: https://github.com/CalogerN/Conquer

Live Preview: https://calogern.github.io/Conquer/

I tried debugging, but I found nothing.

```css
.section-e__btn {
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin: 28px 0px 30px 20px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
```

```html
<div class="section-e__column1">

  <a href="#" class="section-e__btn">Read more</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: The problem is an `<a>` tag is an inline element. Add `display: inline-block` to the `btn`. https://medium.com/@DaphneWatson/css-display-properties-block-inline-and-inline-block-how-to-tell-the-difference-7d3a1e6e3051

Comment: @disinfor If I knew the answer I wouldn't post the question

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli I'm not sure what you mean. I gave you the answer, a reference link for more reading and a question that already has the answer for the question you asked.

Comment: @disinfor I mean you marked it as duplicate, but it wasn't my intention to duplicate anything. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @CalogeroNapoli I know you weren't trying to duplicate anything, but the answer already exists on Stack Overflow - so the community uses flags to point users to existing questions/answers so the site doesn't get cluttered with the same type of question. It's all good, it happens. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to set margins on the `<a>` tag.